# asyncio multiple infinite loops using selenium

Tags: python, multithreading, selenium, python-asyncio

I'm trying to translate a thread-based script into an asyncio-based script. I'm trying to run multiple concurrent mycheck() coroutines that are infinite loops. I'm having difficulties because inside this mycheck function that will be a coroutine, I call both function (some_http_request_function) and object methods, using selenium library in order to automatize browser. I don't know which function should be defined as async and which parts of code shall be awaited. Here my thread-based code I want to speed up:

```
class foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.drivers=[]
        for j in range(2):
            self.drivers.append(webdriver.Chrome("chromedriver.exe"))
        self.list1=["foo","bar"]
        self.urls=["url1","url2"]
    def method1(self,index):
        return self.list1[index]

    def method2(self,index):
        if index==1:
            return self.method3(index)
        else:
            return self.method4(index)
    def method3(self,index):
        if self.drivers[index]==None:
            self.drivers[index]=webdriver.Chrome("chromedriver.exe")
        self.drivers[index].get(self.urls[index])
        try:
            self.drivers[index].find_element_by_xpath("xpath-example")
            if availability.text != "Some text":
                self.drivers[index].close()
                self.drivers[index]=None
                return true
            else:
                self.drivers[index].close()
                self.drivers[index]=None
                return false
        except Exception as e:
            self.drivers[index].close()
            self.drivers[index]=None
            return false

def some_http_request_function(element):
    response = requests.get(element)
    return response.json()


def mycheck(index):
    while True:
        print("started")
        availability=bot.method2(index)
        if availability:
            some_http_request_function(bot.method1(index))
            while availability:
                time.sleep(300)
                availability = bot.method2(index)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    bot = foo()
    for i in range(2):
        t = Thread(target=mycheck, args=(i,))
        t.start()
```

I tried by making these changes:

```
class foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.drivers=[]
        for j in range(2):
            self.drivers.append(webdriver.Chrome("chromedriver.exe"))
        self.list1=["foo","bar"]
        self.urls=["url1","url2"]
    def method1(self,index):
        return self.list1[index]

    async def method2(self,index):
        if index==1:
            return await self.method3(index)
        else:
            return await self.method4(index)
    async def method3(self,index):
        if self.drivers[index]==None:
            self.drivers[index]=webdriver.Chrome("chromedriver.exe")
        self.drivers[index].get(self.urls[index])
        try:
            self.drivers[index].find_element_by_xpath("xpath-example")
            if availability.text != "Some text":
                self.drivers[index].close()
                self.drivers[index]=None
                return true
            else:
                self.drivers[index].close()
                self.drivers[index]=None
                return false
        except Exception as e:
            self.drivers[index].close()
            self.drivers[index]=None
            return false

def some_http_request_function(element):
    response = requests.get(element)
    return response.json()


async def mycheck(index):
    while True:
        print("started")
        availability= await bot.method2(index)
        if availability:
            some_http_request_function(bot.method1(index))
            while availability:
                await asyncio.sleep(300)
                availability = await bot.method2(index)


async def main():
    await asyncio.gather(mycheck(0),mycheck(1))



if __name__ == '__main__':
    bot = foo()
    asyncio.run(main())
```

but I'm pretty sure the code is not executed as I wish because the two "started" prints are not close to one another. I expected them to run together. What am I doing wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure you really want async methods for anything to do with webdriver methods since they need to be in a specific order (i.e. go to url then find element then... etc...)  Are you doing this just to speed up each thread?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to speed up the threads. I don't know why but with 4 threads (i.e. 4 concurrent mycheck() functions) it seems pretty slow and don't seem independent from each other

Comment: I don't know python, but it looks like you only have 2 different webdrivers.  That'd be 2 threads/driver objects/browsers.   The methods to the drivers seem like they'd need to be in some kind of order.  If you wanted async finds only for each, maybe that's possible but it seems like that would need to be at the webdriver level of things.  Don't think you can control that.  Might be worth noting that async != threads.  It just means they're not blocking calls on the current thread.... and your code runs outside of the webdriver.